# how to resolve the zone already loaded error in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, zonejs

Im trying to load my angular build from a typescript package using (dist/index.html). Its loading fine, but when im going back and again trying to load the same, its showing the below errors.

VM5485:1 Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
    at new d (:1:211206)

VM5457:1 Uncaught Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.

I tried:
removing the zone.js from polyfills.ts and adding "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4".

But no luck. Can someone please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding zone.js: 0.9.0 in the package.json and run npm install. The issue will get resolved.

Comment: Facing same issue all of a sudden. Using zone.js 0.9.1. Current Chrome version is 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) (64-bit). Not sure as why facing this issue now as all was working fine since last build made with 0.9.1 zone.js (more than a year ago)